# Moving Wordpress site to /blog domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, virtualhost

I have a client with a wordpress site located on example.com, however, they want a custom website on example.com and the blog moving to example.com/blog

So far I have created two folders in the root directory

```
/main
/blog
```

In the virtual host, I have an Alias for the blog

```
Alias /blog /var/www/public_html/blog
```

The main site is located in the /main folder and everything seems to be working fine. The wordpress site has been moved to the /blog folder and when I goto /blog it does indeed load up.

**Two problems**

1) Style sheets aren't loading for the wordpress site. In the source they appear to be example.com/wp-content/... rather than example.com/blog/wp-content/...

2) Links appear correct but don't goto the desired place. For example a category named clothing appears as example.com/blog/category/clothing/ but when clicked redirects to example.com

**UPDATE**

In wp-options table I updated the siteurl and home values to include the /blog This is solved issue 1. Issue 2 remains.

**UPDATE**

The problem appears to be with the Virtual Host Alias. /blog catches and goes to the public_html/blog folder, /blog/anything doesn't catch and goes to the /main folder.

**UPDATE AND SOLUTION**

The problem was with the .htaccess within the wordpress site.

This is the original .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is a modification that works

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /blog
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule    (.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "[WP Migrate DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/)" plugin - it will create a data base dump and will replace all old url's to new ones.

Comment: This is also an important step to take. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1)

Solved by updating the table 'wp-options' setting values of the 'siteurl' and 'home' to include the '/blog/' suffix

Problem 2)

Solved by updating the wordpress .htaccess file to this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /blog
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule    (.*) index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hey, I am in the same situation and everyting it workks BUT when enable the permalinks I cannot open the site cause of "Too many redirections"
Do you have an idea how I can handle that?